# load local css file in SPFx webpart

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

this is the html file contains referecence to local css files in same directory.

demo.html

```
 <title>Demo Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/swiper.css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="simplecontainer">
```

Now I created a SPFx web part(with reactJs) and contains same html element, so I need to load these css files.. how can I make this works as it in the html page above.

if they were small, I can copy and paste all into "myweppart.module.scss" ? but its not efficient I think

EDITED:

```
export default class AnnouncementsWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IAnnouncementsProps> {
public constructor() {
    super();
    SPComponentLoader.loadCss('../mylocalcssfile.css');
```

Can i load css files this way ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Upload your css files to Style Library. You can find style library from site content and give URL of that css to

```
SPComponentLoader.loadCss('file path here')
```

you can see file path from style library, select your css file click on ECB menu and select get a link or open file.[image: get a link]

Comment: Thanks @Jinesh, What abt multiple environments? Is there anyway to give relative URL of SharePoint style library path?